# Is there any method to install packages in centos without using sudo or yum command?

Tags: centos, sudo, yum

Am looking for a method through which I can download and install packages without a sudo. What I really would like to know is the method which permits me to install packages without super user involvement.

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  You can *download* a package from the [repositories](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/) using only a browser.  Do you really just want to download them, or do you want to do something else with them afterwards (such as running the packaged application)?

Comment: What am really expecting is, I want to download Django in CentOS and install it. But am having a restraint about not having admin privileges. And thank you so much for such a quick response!

Comment: OK, the "and install it" step is the important bit where you'd normally need admin privileges, so that's worth mentioning in your question.

Comment: is there any possible solution for this or not??

Comment: You could ask your sysadmin to install `pip` & `virtualenv` - [There's a tutorial here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/common-python-tools-using-virtualenv-installing-with-pip-and-managing-packages). From there, you could create your own virtual environment and install Django: [The docs are here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/#installing-an-official-release-with-pip).

Comment: @RohanShah There are always solutions. Virtually _any_ software can be installed in a user's home directory. The crux is that it may require quite a lot of work. Unfortunately I can't answer your question as I'm not a Linux user. You should update the question with what software you want to install (it's mentioned in a comment, but it should really be part of the question). If you have further info that may help someone with CentOS knowledge to answer (I don't know what this may be), then add this in the question as well.